# global variable not working in sub-function of Angular 7

Tags: angular, global-variables

## I'm have a question please explain for me

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, debounceTime, tap, switchAll, count } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http:Http) {

   }
   @ViewChild('abcde') abcde: ElementRef;
   private typeTerm = new Subject<string>();
   public result:string="";
}
```

## And Function Call variable **result**

```
fTyping(a){
  this.result="abcd"; //It Working
  if(this.timeout){ clearTimeout(this.timeout);}
  this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    this.result="efgh"; //**Not Working**
    const url="http://localhost:81/api/films/GetFilms",body=JSON.stringify({username:"admin",password:"admin",page:1,"search":a,sort:this.txtSort});
    const requestHeader = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    http1.post(url,body,{ headers : requestHeader }).toPromise().then(res=>{
    temp=res.json();
    console.log(res.json().length);
    this.isLoading=false;
    if(res.json().length<10){
      this.isData=false;
    }
    else
      this.isData=true;
    }).catch(x=>{
      this.result=JSON.stringify({Name:"No data",Title:"No Data",Manufacture:"No Data",Country:"No Data"});
      this.isLoading=false;
      this.isData=false;
    });
  },500);
}
```

> Problem: Why in function *setTimeout* **this.result** not woking. Is there any way for it to work in function **setTimeout**?

Comment: Try using arrow function for setTimeout callback `setTimeout(() => {`

Comment: Thanks you save me! Thank you very much.I'm so grateful ♥♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually setTimeout create its own this scope in side function that is why it is not working you can store reference of this in another variable

```
var that=this;
this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    that.result="efgh"; //use that

  },500);
```

or you can use arrow function (arrow function do not create its own this scope)

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.result="efgh";
},500)
```